# Where is this brightly coloured house in Koskinou, Rhodes?

Tags: where-on-earth, greece

I am looking for the location of a house, I know it is in Koskinou village in Rhodes, but I want the exact location.

[This is the google map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Koskinou+851+00%E5%B8%8C%E8%87%98/@36.3866885,28.2132736,18z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x14956151648d267d:0x6a62d7686b12a0e8!2zS29za2lub3UgODUxIDAw5biM6IeY!3b1!8m2!3d36.3871398!4d28.2138691!3m4!1s0x14956151648d267d:0x6a62d7686b12a0e8!8m2!3d36.3871398!4d28.2138691)

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the question is now it is likely to be closed, as 'no use for others' or one of the other standard reasons to close questions. Can you please add why you want to know the location and what use it is to others to have this answered?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is just personal favor and 'no use for others', i am new and i don't know the rules on this website, if this bothers you, close the question as you want.

Comment: We have had a troll that kept posting poor quality photos with a 'where is this' questions, which is why we are sharp on it. I will not close this question but leave it up to the community. Nice place by the way.

Comment: that's a good game of geoguessr.

Answer (score 7):

Well, that took a long time to find.... The colours are much more faded on Google Maps (don't know about real life?), but I'm confident this is it.

It's on 28is Oktovriou, near the western end of that street, close to the cliff, right on the nearly 90° bend towards the south, at 36.385744913006974, 28.212052853156727.

Click on picture to get to the location on Google Maps:

[image]

Comment: I spent a while on Satellite View myself but I completely forgot that 3D view was an option.  ::: facepalm :::

Comment: Also, [xkcd has something to say about that level of precision on GPS coordinates.](https://xkcd.com/2170/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert eh eh apparently Google Maps must be counting atoms :-)